# Bind GNSS receiver with android app over bluetooth

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I'm looking to integrate a GNSS receiver with a Smartphone app. I've found only GNSS receivers that are meant to communicate only with their mobile interface, they don't provide any documentation for integrating smartphone apps in the workflow of using GNSS receivers.

Any ideas about communicating with existing GNSS receivers? If not, what are the available options ?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while (i.e., years) since I've looked at this, but the last time I researched this the Bluetooth [Serial Port Profile (SPP)](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/SPP.aspx) was your best option.  If there isn't any explicit documentation for an interface, you basically have to hope that the receiver outputs its data via the Bluetooth SPP, and that your Android device supports SPP.

There are known issues with this, though, depending on the receiver manufacturer and specific Android device.  See the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543638/how-to-get-bluetooth-rfcomm-to-work-consistently
http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/pairing-spp-bluetooth-devices-with-android-phones.html

There are some Android apps that claim to do this out-of-the-box:

- [Bluetooth GPS Output](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps&hl=en)
- [Bluetooth SPP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.dzs.android.BluetoothSPP&hl=en)

...although I haven't personally tried them, and depending on your specific devices your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many GNSS RTK receivers.

Example:
STONEX GNSS or North GNSS that they send NMEA to the Bluetooth.

Also you could read the manuals from Javad and other GNSS vendors to integrate in your application their GNSS futures.

You can use the SSP example to connect to them.
Example Application is on Google Play, the MyRTK.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS you are looking at, perhaps the Leica Zeno 20 Android would fit your needs? http://leica-geosystems.com/products/gis-collectors/gis-handhelds-tablets/leica-zeno-20